# How to implement From<u8> for integer enum

Tags: rust

With an:

```rust
enum Foo {
  Bar,
  Doe,
}
```

I want to be able to create an instance of `Foo` via e.g. `let doe: Foo = 1.into()`.
Now I tried implementing `From<u8>` but cannot seem to make match working.

The following naive code does not work:

```rust
match b {
  Foo::Doe as u8 => Foo::Doe,
}
```

How is one supposed to easily match all enum variants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the "naive" way of matching, you have to realize that obviously not every `u8` will map onto a variant of your enum. Hence you can't use `From` but instead should use `TryFrom`. Then you just do

```rust
match b {
  1 => Ok(Bar),
  2 => Ok(Doe), 
  _ => Err(whatever_error_type_you_use)
}
```

But if you don't want to do it in a pedestrian way, you can use a custom crate like this one https://crates.io/crates/int-enum

Comment: Thanks. Went with https://crates.io/crates/num-enum